# How to compare whether two subclasses have the same superclasses?

Tags: python

Currently I am learning Python and the concept of inheritance. When I tried to create one class called `Animal` and its subclass `Rabbit`. I also want to create the specific method to create a baby `Rabbit` from two mating ones and compare if two baby `Rabbit`s have same parents.

However when I tried to compare them using the sample below,

```
r1 = Rabbit(3)
r2 = Rabbit(4)
r3 = r1+r2
r4 = r1+r2
print(r3 == r4)
```

I first used as follows (rid is just the sequential tag for each instance created)

```
parents_same = self.parent1.rid == other.parent1.rid \
               and self.parent2.rid == other.parent2.rid
parents_opposite = self.parent2.rid == other.parent1.rid \
                   and self.parent1.rid == other.parent2.rid
return parents_same or parents_opposite
```

It went right, but when I tried to use:

```
parents_same = self.parent1 == other.parent1 \
               and self.parent2 == other.parent2
parents_opposite = self.parent2 == other.parent1 \
                   and self.parent1 == other.parent2
return parents_same or parents_opposite
```

It showed that `NoneType` object has no attribute `parent1`. Moreover, when I revise the code that make the debugging easier, it went to say `self` is type "string" and not have the attribute `parent1`. I am totally at loss with such a situation.

key code that I used and may be useful for reference:

```
class Rabbit(Animal):
tag = 1
def __init__(self, age, parent1=None, parent2=None):
    Animal.__init__(self, age)
    self.parent1 = parent1
    self.parent2 = parent2
    self.rid = Rabbit.tag
    Rabbit.tag += 1
def get_rid(self):
    return str(self.rid).zfill(3)
def get_parent1(self):
    return self.parent1
def get_parent2(self):
    return self.parent2
def __add__(self, other):
    # returning object of same type as this class
    return Rabbit(0, self, other)
def __eq__(self, other):
    # compare the ids of self and other's parents
    parents_same = self.parent1.rid == other.parent1.rid \
                   and self.parent2.rid == other.parent2.rid
    parents_opposite = self.parent2.rid == other.parent1.rid \
                       and self.parent1.rid == other.parent2.rid
    return parents_same or parents_opposite
def __str__(self):
    return "rabbit:"+ self.get_rid()
```

Comment: What you currently are writing is that two Rabbit objects are the same if their parents are the same, you probably do not want `__eq__` for this, also adding two Rabbits does not make sense. I would create separate methods for these things.

Comment: Your full code does not include any sample _usage_ of the classes, pleased [edit[ it and add that so there's a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created a usage example there.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with superclasses. Also, using `+` and `==` for this is bizarre.

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself with two definitions of parent. One is a superclass (which is `Animal` in your example), and the other is an actual parental figure. Checking for the same parental figures has nothing to do with sub/superclasses. Aside from that, please produce a minimal and reproducible example including the code that "says self is type string".
If you want help from SO, you need to focus your question some more

Answer (score -1):

Checking for sibling hood is not what people expect == to do.  Not even you, in this case:  your equality method calls *itself* on the parents rather than some other notion of equality.  This eventually ends up being called on objects who have no parents (or rather parents of None).

Nonetheless, this should not throw an error in this specific example, as the rabbits you're comparing (r3 and r4) have an equal number of generations.  But they will always compare equal, as will (r1 and r2), because None compares equal to None.

If you must have this weird equality operator that instead tests for sibling hood, you should at least check the parents are the same using the python `is`, which will not have this recursive behavior.
If you compare r1 to r3 you will definitely get an error, however.